# Do I need an "K8s service" for each microservice in Kubernetes for internal service communication?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, service-discovery

I will end up having around 20 microservices on the Kubernetes cluster eventually. I am thinking "services meshes" like Istio are overkill. if I have to do just basic **"service discovery and communication"** within each of the 20 microservices with 1 external ingress/LB (**for public traffic**), do I need to create a K8's **'service'** type for each of the 20 microservices so that they can call each other over http/grpc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, you need a `Service` for everything you call. `Service` is a LoadBalancer, it spreads the load and hides the scale and placement of the underlying pods, plus it gives you a service discovery based on DNS.